# AWS-Angular-docker not working

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

I have an angular app which is dockerized. My docker file is:

```
FROM node:8.9 as node
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app/

RUN npm install
COPY ./ /app/

ARG env=prod

RUN npm run build -- --prod --environment $env

FROM nginx:1.13

COPY --from=node /app/dist/ /usr/share/nginx/html

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY ./nginx-custom.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

EXPOSE 4200
#CMD npm start
```

I run 'docker build -t app:prod .' to build my docker app locally and I run it with 'docker run -p 4200:4200 app:prod'. This works perfectly find.

I now build my docker app with 'docker build - t app .', then I tagged it as latest, I pushed it to AWS into the repository, create cluser, task etc.

Everything looks ok in AWS EC2 - but when I use my browser with the public IP and port 4200 I cannot connect to my app.

When I try to run 'docker run -p 4200:4200 app' I get following message:
Unable to find image 'app:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for app, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'.
See 'docker run --help'.

Not sure this is relevant but I am wondering why I cannot start my app this way?

Any idea what I can check on AWS to find the issue?

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 0):

Add the proper name - when you tag it "app" Docker is looking in the main registry.

```
docker build -t your.remote.repository/michael/app .
```

And then run it:

```
docker run -p 4200:4200 your.remote.repository/michael/app
```

Proper tagging is important so Docker can find its way to the correct place.

Comment: Thanks ! I did this - removed 'CMD NPM START' from docker file since it created an error but then it worked locally with this image. But still this doesnt resolve my issue with AWS - I still do not get my app running in AWS.